# SSMS closes after installing visual studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2017

Good Morning.
I have a problem, first I made the installation of SQL Server Express, followed by SSMS and finally Visual Studio Community.

Before installing visual studio, SMMS worked perfectly, when you install visual studio, SSMS is sorry, the logo appears and opens the window to connect to the server but it immediately closes. Also if I try to uninstall SSMS the same thing happens with the installer, it closes when it appears.

SSMS V. 17.9.1

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a problem with your Visual C++ Redistributable not being the version required by SSMS. Check which version of the VC++ Redistributable is required by SSMS and if you have a later version already installed, then uninstall it. If you have an older version, then download the version required by SSMS and install it manually. Normally I find this problem when developers install Visual Studio before installing SSMS (as Visual Studio comes packaged with a newer version than SSMS does). You can upgrade the VC++ Redistributable after installing SSMS if you need it.